# Examples of functions whose arc-length from the origin is given by their derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, examples-counterexamples, plane-curves, arc-length

I'm looking for functions $y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}} dx = \frac{dy}{dx}\Bigg|_{a}$$

(this kind of feels like a calculus-of-variations type problem, but I don't have any experience with the calculus of variations)

Comment: Looks like a differential equations problem to me. Differentiate both side with respect to $a$. (Makes me uncomfortable, $a$ is usually a constant.  Why not in the integral have $\frac{dy}{dt}$, and upper limit of integration $x$?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solutions are 
$y(x) = A + \cosh(x)$ for arbitrary constants $A$.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: A [catenary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary#Derivation_of_equations_for_the_curve)